# Does Google + API can be used for both custom domain and gmail?

Tags: google-api, google-plus

Does Google + API can be used for both custom domain Google + accounts along with gmail accounts ? 
 I have done some research on this and I found that there are two types of Google + API's, one is simply **Google + API** and other is **Google + Domain API** . 
 I want to use Google + api so that I can verify the emails of the workers whether they are Gmail user or Google Business Account holder. 
 I'm confused between these two API, I want to know that does Google + API only work with gmail account only or it also support custom domains (Gsuite )

Comment: show us your research and attempts so far.

Comment: I have done some updation in the post.

Comment: the 2nd api (G+ domain) is exclusively for GSuite domains. The first one is for either. This is easily verifiable by making an api call with both, for example from the oauth2 playground.

Comment: Thank you I got my answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the 2nd one (Google+ domain API) is exclusively for GSuite domains. The first one (Google+ API) is for either.

This is easily verifiable by making an api call from each account, for example from the [Google Oauth2 playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/).